New shoots on spruce trees with photo
I have several spruce trees in my yard. They are close together and a few years ago I removed the dead branches from the bottom of the trees (the trees range in height from 15 to 35 feet and around 4 to 7 feet was pruned from the bottoms). This year I noticed most of the trees have new branch shoots coming off the existing branches and trunks... Is this a good sign? I have tried looking all over the internet for answers and cannot find anything definitive.

what is your concern?

This type of tree is new to me and I am just wanting to make sure that this is a not a sign of a sick tree... From the answers I have already received, it seems as though this is good for the tree.

Most coniferous evergreens have new shoots from the branches and top every year. That's how they grow.
New growth from the trunk where it's heavily shaded by the top branches is unusual, but not concerning.
It's unlikely to come to much as it will still be heavily shaded by the branches above and might well give up and die. If you want the trunks clear, go ahead and trim those off. If you'd like branches down there, you can let them grow, but don't be surprised if they die anyway from being too shaded.
Usually the only way to have branches right to the ground is annual pruning to impose a more tapered form than the natural growth habit, so the lower branches get enough sun at their tips to keep growing. Once lower branches have died out it's all-but-impossible to get them back to the point that they are longer than the branches above and likely to live long.

Thanks for the answer, I also figured out how to add a photo to the question.

I don't think it means anything. Its not a bad sign. If you have pruned a lot, then it may be a survival mode thing.

Thanks for the answer, I figured out how to add a photo to my question in case it helps.
